# Scripted alerts in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, alerts

Being novice, I'd like to understand how scripted alerts work. For example, here
below is an alert which is supposed to trigger every 5 minutes provided the selected instrument and time frame are correct.

The scripts seem ok as per the console but do not work. Hence my questions:

- What could be the reasons?
- Can you confirm scripted alerts are not automatically added to the list of alerts (right hand side pane)?
- How could I define several scripted alerts (e.g. same condition and time frame but different fixed instruments)?
- Optionally, does a function return the number of elements of a string array?

--- example 1:

```
//@version=4
study("temp", overlay = true)
score_val=0.5
if syminfo.tickerid=="AAPL" and timeframe.period=='5' and score_val==0.5
    alert(syminfo.tickerid + "_1",alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

--- example 2:

```
//@version=4
study("temp", overlay = true)
nb_tickers=1
var string[] stringArray= array.from("AAPL")

for i = 0 to nb_tickers-1
    if syminfo.tickerid==array.get(stringArray,i) and timeframe.period=='5' and score_val==0.5
        alert(syminfo.tickerid + "_1",alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to trigger alerts on multiple symbols in the [blog post announcement](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/).

`alert()` calls in scripts trigger alert events; they do not create alerts. The alerts need to be created from the chart UI using ALT-A or this button:

[image]

See the [Pine usrman on alerts for more information](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html).